# Merge de commit especifico

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Eu estou trabalhando atualmente em uma migração de SCM na minha empresa, estamos passando de CVS para Git, porém o código no CVS era versionado de uma forma diferente, cada branch é um code-base diferente, dessa forma, gostaria de saber como faço para conseguir mergear apenas um commit por vez com o Git.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cherry Picking

Cada commit em um repositório corresponde a uma tree cheia de arquivos. Normalmente, esses arquivos foram criados ao longo de vários commits. Mas, às vezes, é necessário levar o delta entre dois commits, e aplicá-lo a um branch diferente, como no seu caso.

Nesse caso, você não quer pegar o estado atual da tree (que pode ter alterações inacabadas ou não testadas); você só quer pegar o delta associado a essa mudança.

Em outros sistemas de controle de versão, você teria apenas que criar um diff com base na mudança mais recente, e depois corrigir a mudança em seu branch de lançamento. Em vez disso, com o Git, podemos usar o comando [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) para fazer o trabalho para nós:

```
git checkout master
echo Working >> file.txt
git commit -m "Working" file.txt
echo BugFix >> bugfix.txt
git commit -m "BugFix" bugfix.txt
echo More Working >> file.txt
git commit -m "More working" file.txt
# Vamos aplicar o 'bugfix' para release
git checkout release10
git cherry-pick master~1
[release10 41037ab] BugFix
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bugfix.txt
```

Isso nos permitiu fazer uma única alteração - descrita aqui com master~1 - e copiar o delta no branch de lançamento.

Se tivéssemos várias mudanças, poderíamos ter master~3..master~1. Ao contrário de apenas gerar um diff e patch da tree atual, isso vai copiar os commits (e suas relações) sobre o novo branch.

### Origem

Finalmente, é interessante notar que, quando você copia uma mudança usando esse mecanismo, o hash de commit vai mudar (notavelmente porque terá uma hierarquia diferente). 
Às vezes, isso não importa, mas se você deseja gravar onde a mudança original veio, você pode executar git cherry-pick-x. Isso insere uma mensagem de commit indicando de onde a mudança original veio:

```
git checkout release10
git cherry-pick -x master~1
git cherry-pick master~1
[release10 41037ab] BugFix (cherry picked from commit 938a4c0bbb3985524192aa8a926ea6757263e94b)
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bugfix.txt
```

É possível também fazer o cherry-pick a partir da SHA do commit, basta fazer achar o commit que você deseja trazer para a sua branch e mandar executar com o comando:

```
git cherry-pick -x b53af978b3581509557c6e24923edf1c8a683e02
```

### Criando um novo histórico

Sempre que você está usando o cherry-pick, principalmente se você estiver reordenando commits, você está criando um novo histórico. No entanto, você nunca realmente joga fora o antigo, tudo está disponível a partir dos reflogs. Você não está destruindo o histórico, você está criando outros alternativos. Todo o cherry picking te dá a capacidade de aplicar os patches de outros branches de uma maneira segura e com menos erros.